# What is the English name for chleb bez maki?

Tags: bread, polish-cuisine

Can't remember how I stumbled onto this but everything I google for chleb bez maki is in Polish. Can't find a Wikipedia article. Is this a traditional polish bread?

What is the English name for it? I see there are chleb bez maki mixes but can't seem to find them online for purchase and even if I did I wouldn't know how to use it. Id like to know the English name. Looks like it's made almost totally out of seeds.

Comment: Do you have an image of it? Just googling "Polish seed bread" gave me this: https://www.mynewroots.org/site/2013/02/the-life-changing-loaf-of-bread/

Comment: 'Chleb bez maki' translates to 'bread without flour'.

Comment: @Cindy when I translated maki I got poppyseeds?

Comment: @Catija I translated the whole phase.

Comment: @catija The actual word is "mąka", flour, and because most Slavic languages have cases, it gets changed to "mąki" in the phrase. This is different from the word "mak" (notice that it uses an actual "a", which is a different letter from "ą") which means "poppy" and has the plural "maki".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Chleb bez mąki** means literally in polish "bread without flour", you may find hundreds of recipes in the web. They are breads based in whole grains, oatmeal, etc...

[Chleb bez mąki](http://veganbanda.pl/recipe/chleb-bez-maki/)